# Fetch and count records by Date

Tags: postgresql, datetime, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I have to make a query to fetch and then count all records with `created_at`, by Date in the time zone:

```
def total_by_date(my_date)    
  where{created_at <= my_date}.count
end
```

`created_at` is stored as `timestamp` in UTC in PostgreSQL, but `my_date` is a Date in Rails's application time zone.

How it could be done right way, without losses because of time zone conversion, and should `created_at` be converted to Date first?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the `where` clause. Is that `total_by_date` being invoked as a scope? Are you using any kind of gems for queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem with a plain 'ol `Date` object is that it contains no time information. So in your query as you presently have it, you would end up getting everything BEFORE the specified date, since the query would resolving to something like `WHERE created_at <= '2013-09-27'...`. One way you can get around this problem without losing records is to simply add 1 day to your date object, like so:

```
def total_by_date(my_date)    
    where{created_at <= (my_date + 1.day)}.count
end
```

In this way too you don't need to worry about timezones at all; you're just looking at the date portion.

**Edit**

In response to your question in the comment:

Regarding why the `+ 1.day` works, think of the date like this: `my_date` comes out looking like `2013-09-24` in the query, but it is basically the same as `2013-09-24 00:00:00`. That would be the same as a datetime/timestamp set to midnight on September 24. So, in plain English, if your comparison is "give me everything on or before midnight September 24", you'll get every result that lands on, and exists earlier than that specific time and date, but anything that happened later in the day on Sept 24 won't show up.

Hence the `+ 1.day` - the same "problem" still exists, except it works in your favour now because our query is now "anything on or before midnight September 25".

**Note:** Technically, you might get undesired matches for anything that happened to be created on exactly midnight September 25, but you can easily change your comparison to simply `<` instead of `<=` to fix that problem.

Comment: Hey Teeg, thanks for your answer. Yea, I forgot to mentioned Squeel here, so generally, everything is fine with the query by itself. Now I'm trying to wrap my head around `+ 1.day` stuff, and figure out why it works (it is! well.. looks like...). Cannot get, why if i for example have `2013-09-24` as `my_date` and `2013-09-24 13:06:22` as `created_at`, `my_date` will be before  the specified date. Weird.

Comment: Think of the date like this: `my_date` comes out looking like `2013-09-24`, but it is basically the same as `2013-09-24 00:00:00`. That would be the same as a datetime/timestamp set to midnight on September 24. So, if your comparison is "anything on or before midnight September 24", you'll get every result that lands on, and exists earlier than that time and date, but anything that happened later in the day on Sept 24 won't show up. Hence the ` + 1.day` - the same "problem" still exists, except it works in your favour now because our query is now "anything on or before midnight September 25".

Comment: @LeoBurt Added more clarification to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, i see. I really appreciate your support. Kudos.

Comment: @LeoBurt No prob. Good luck.